# Сочетание «определяющим образом»

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли использовать сочетание «определяющим образом». Встретился следующий вариант его употребления: «Они не только характеризуют уголовно-правовую действительность в целом, но и определяющим образом влияют на признание того или иного поведения лиц, преступным или непреступным».

Answer (score 1):

Здесь - да, возможно. "Определяющим образом" означает, что некие "они" не просто как-то влияют, а **определяют**, играют главенствующую роль в плане результата оценки поведения упомянутых лиц. "Определённым образом" не годится. Это не означало бы доминанту этих "они".

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, все-таки 'определенным образом'. Приведенный вами контекст не позволяет более точно ответить на ваш вопрос.